# Get wmi object process and create a command doesn't work

Tags: powershell

I have this powershell snippet:

```
$command = "taskkill /F /IM aaaa.exe"
$process = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_process -ComputerName 1.1.1.1
$result = $process.Create($command)
```

And i'm trying to Create a command to run on this but it keeps saying that create doesnt exist on wmiobject.

Before that i was using [WMICLASS] but thi doesn't work on an app i'm trying to run powershell on so i'm trying to figure yout alternatives.

This was a working example (outside of the app where i'm tyring to make it run):

```
$command2 = "C:\aaaa.exe"
$process2 = [WMICLASS]"\\1.1.1.1\ROOT\CIMV2:win32_process"
$result2 = $process2.Create($command2)
```

I'm just trying to replace WMICLASS but can't find how. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `Invoke-WmiMethod`:

```
$Command = 'taskkill /F /IM aaaa.exe'
$ComputerName = '1.1.1.1'

$WmiArgs = @{
    'Class'        = 'Win32_Process'
    'Name'         = 'Create'
    'ArgumentList' = $Command
    'ComputerName' = $ComputerName
    # 'Credential' = (Get-Credential) #if needed
}
$Response = Invoke-WmiMethod @WmiArgs

$Response
```

Comment: This works as an alternative but i have the same issue in the app. I'll find another solution. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @John what do you mean "in the app"?

Comment: I'm trying to run this in Bamboo, it has a poweshell compiler but it's crap and not understanding everything i think. But i run jmeter also so as first test in jmeter i will run my powershell until atlassian answers why bamboo's powershell is not working.

Comment: @John Did you see what's in the `$Response` when run from Bamboo? It's possibly a permissions issue with WMI.

Comment: 09-May-2018 17:33:01 C:\Users\Administrator\bamboo-home\xml-data\build-dir\CE-CET-JMET>'ComputerName' = 'x' 
09-May-2018 17:33:01 ''ComputerName'' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
09-May-2018 17:33:01 operable program or batch file.

Comment: the x in computer nam is an ip i just replaced for the comment. And this is triggered for every property. he also says $command is not an external or internal method so yeah. I think something's broken with their compiler.

Comment: @John It's trying to run it from `cmd.exe` is the problem, not `powershell.exe`.

Comment: Oh yeah forgot to switch for this one. It says access is denied now :(

Comment: @John Looks like you'll need to specify a credential

Comment: How do i write in Get-Credential? Cause get-credential is prompting me for credentials. Cna i set them in a parameter?

Comment: @John You can pass credentials as a parameter, but then they'd be exposed to system process logging.  The "best" way would be to have some application inside the script retrieving credentials but I'm assuming that's not possible.  The "best practice" way would be to log into the server bamboo runs on, start a process as the bamboo user (probably NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM, use `psexec -s cmd`), and create the credentials to be used from there (`Get-Credential | Export-CliXml -path 'C:\mycreds.xml'`) then import them when the script runs: `$cred = Import-CliXml -path 'C:\mycreds.xml'`